# programatic check/un-check of nested checkboxes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, checkbox

I am using AngularJS to hide a series of checkboxes from data in a JSON array.

The following needs to be achieved.

1. Open the nest on checking the parent
2. Display the active checkboxes
3. Remove (splice from activeFilters array) by unchecking and also clicking on the name of the item.
4. Be able to clear all checkboxes.

I am 90% of the way to completion: see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taylorsuk/a6cp3v5r/).

Problems are:

1. The correct removal binding only works on the top level (equipment).
2. I am unable to splice a single item out of the array and it bind correctly (i mean remove the checkbox and the active `<li>` element).
3. Is this going to be suitable for a production app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem 1, you have it right in your `$scope.clearFilters` code:

```
angular.forEach($scope.Filters[0].filters, function(filter) {
```

i.e. you are checking only the first set. You'll need to use another level of nesting, for example like:

```
angular.forEach($scope.Filters, function (filtersGroup) {
  angular.forEach(filtersGroup.filters, function(filter) {
    // etc
```

For problem 2, I'm not sure what you are trying to do now.

```
<li ng-model="activeFilter.checked" ng-click="removeFilter(ModifyFilter(activeFilter.checked,activeFilter))">
```

Things noted here:

1. You don't have a `removeFilter` function introduced, only `removeSingleFilter`
2. And anyway, your `ModifyFilter` function doesn't return anything, that could be used as a parameter for another function.
3. Lastly, you don't change your `activeFilter.checked` to false before invoking `ModifyFilter` -> `ModifyFilter` tries to push another copy of the `activeFilter` to `$scope.ActiveFilters`, causing a duplicate error:

> "Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: activeFilter in ActiveFilters, Duplicate key: object:00E
>   
>   Fix for this is simply setting `activeFilter.checked` to false, and then invoking only `ModifyFilter` (which perhaps isn't the best name for the function, but anyway does it's job just fine). Here a naive approach:

```
<li ng-model="activeFilter.checked" ng-click="activeFilter.checked = !activeFilter.checked; ModifyFilter(activeFilter.checked,activeFilter)"
```

But perhaps using a function might be cleaner, something like this:

```
$scope.deactivateFilter = function (filter) {
    filter.checked = !filter.checked;
    $scope.ModifyFilter(filter.checked, filter);
};
```

and use it simply like this:

```
<li ng-model="activeFilter.checked" ng-click="deactivateFilter(activeFilter)">
```

And lastly, I'd perhaps also refactor your `ModifyFilter` function simply to take only one parameter, `filter`, and pick `filter.checked` inside the function.

As to your third question: can't really say. With these fixes, I don't see any huge problems with this approach. But don't take my word for granted... :)

Comment: All works really nicely apart from the deactivateFilter function doesn't uncheck the checkboxes.

Comment: Hm, that's a bit odd, as I got it working just fine. Unfortunately I didn't save my jsfiddle, so I can't share it now :(

Comment: Ok, I see your problem in the current approach. Previously, you pushed the whole `filter` object (with `name` and `checked` property) to your `$scope.ActiveFilters` array. In that case, you will have reference to the **same** `filter` object both in your `ActiveFilters` as well as in `Filters`. Now you are pushing only the `filter.name` property, and so you don't any longer have the reference to the `filter` object in `ActiveFilters`. So, either change it back to pushing whole `filter` object, or do the unchecking correctly in `deactivateFilter` (find the `filter` object based on name etc.)